# Storing Google Places API data - is it allowed?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm creating a website that is essentially a directory of US businesses that fall within a niche category. In order to populate the database, I'm using the Google Places API to gather a list of business names and addresses that meet my criteria.

Am I allowed to store this data indefinitely? I couldn't find any documentation that explicitly prohibited storing Places API data, but I know that other APIs have limitations on how long you can keep the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not allowed according to the terms of use. Applications that use the Google Places API must adhere to the Google Maps/Google Earth API Terms of Service as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview#Requirements):

> All applications that use the Google Places or Google Places
> Autocomplete APIs must adhere to the requirements described in the
> Developer Policies and the Google Maps/Google Earth API Terms of
> Service. The Google Places API and the Google Places Autocomplete API
> share a usage quota as described in the Usage Limits documentation.

The [Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service section 10.1.3 (b)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3) do not allow storing of content for purposes other than temporary caching:

> You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you
> may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving
> the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so
> temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days),
> securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content
> outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that
> the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For
> example, you must not use the Content to create an independent
> database of "places" or other local listings information.

So no, you are not allowed to store this data indefinitely.

Comment: Recent policy changes removed the 30 days caching statement and added a statement about not cacheing any ratings data. When asked for clarification from Google, Google stated any and all data cached from Places API must be deleted.